# is there any statistical test for independence in this situation?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

I wonder if there is a statistical test which fits my need.

Let $X=(X_1,...,X_n) ,Y=(Y_1,...,Y_n)$ be $n$-dimensional random vectors.

Is there any statistical test to check whether $X_1,...,X_n$ are more mutually independent than $Y_1,...,Y_n$?

Comment: What do you mean by "more mutually independent"?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I don't know how to formally defined this.. but there really exists a such concept in nature..  What does it mean when the correlation of a pair is smaller than the correlation of another pair?

Comment: If $X_i$ and $Y_i$ have the same marginal distributions, it may make sense to compare the Kullback-Liebler divergences $$D(P_{X_1, ..., X_n}||P_{X_1}...P_{X_n}) \underset{?}{\geq}D(P_{Y_1, ..., Y_n}||P_{Y_1}...P_{Y_n})$$

Answer (score 0):

As @Robert Israel already stated, this depends on what you mean by "more mutually independent".

In the strict sense of probability theory, random variables are either independent or not. So, the only way $X_1,X_2$ can be more mutually independent than $Y_1,Y_2$ is if the former are independent and the latter aren't.

But if you formally define "independence" to be some quantitative criterion, this will generally get you a test.
Which definition is the right one depends on your problem.

For example, you could be interested in whether the mean-squared correlation in the first group is larger than in the second.
You might use the following statistic:
$$
T=\frac{2}{n(n-1)}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j\neq i}E[(X_i-EX_i)(X_j-EX_j)]^2-\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j\neq i}E[(Y_i-EY_i)(Y_j-EY_j)]^2\right)
$$
The empirical version of $T$, say $t$, can be calculated readily.
If $t$ is significantly different from zero, you could say with high probability that one group is more dependent than the other, according to this definition.
Which distribution it follows under $H_0$ depends on your model.

In general, by quantitatively defining what it means to be "more independent", you create a mapping from the random variables $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ into $\mathbb{R}$.
So you'll get two "independence scores" $T(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ and $T(Y_1,\dots,Y_n)$, one of which will be (weakly) larger.
To test whether this difference is significant, you could then perform a statistical test under distributional assumptions adequate to your situation.

Comment: Why is the estimator $T$ a t-distribution? Moreover, let's say that the map $T$ is the total correlation. If the total correlation of $X$ is smaller than $Y$, is it reasonable to say that $X$ is more independent in this sense? I'm confused because I think the relation  $KL(a|b)<KL(c|d)$ does not say that distribution $a&b$ are more closer than $c&d$..

Comment: I did not say that $T$ follows a Student-$t$-distribution, although used the letters $T$ and $t$. Whether it is reasonable to calculate the "total correlation" to measure "independence" is indeed questionable (e.g. being uncorrelated does not imply being independent). I just mean this as a simple example for a general concept. Whether the KL-divergence is related to some distance between distributions of the random variables is a separate question.